# : Troubleshooting: 'snake.exe' Not Found Error in Visual Studio Debugging - Need Assistance

Tags: c#

"I'm encountering an issue with my project in Visual Studio. The error message states that the executable 'snake.exe' specified in the 'snake' debug profile does not exist at the path 'C:\Users\shera\source\repos\snake\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows'. I've checked the path, rebuilt the project, and verified the debug configuration, but the problem persists. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?"